# How do I apply the fixes suggested from the App Review Board to my app?

Tags: application-development

I [submitted my app to the Ubuntu Software Centre](https://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/), and it just got reviewed by the [Ubuntu App Review Board](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppReviewBoard) (ARB).

I got an e-mail suggesting some fixes, and I'm not sure about the next steps I should follow to fix my app.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, **read carefully what the reviewer is asking you to do on the e-mail**. It will generally be either a request for information or a prompt to address some issues with your app.

In all cases:

- Reply to the information request using the *Feedback* tab on your submission in [My Apps](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/)
- Optionally, if you don't receive a reply in a few days, send an e-mail reminder to the ARB mailing list.

[image]

If the ARB has done some changes to your app, apply those changes:

- **Merge changes** - The e-mail you got most probably contains a link to a branch with some suggested changes.

  - Run `bzr merge lp:<branch-with-the-fixes>` on your source tree to merge in the changes
  - Then commit them with the `bzr commit` command (or optionally `quickly save` if you use Quickly)
- **Build and upload a new package** - Build a new package after you've applied the changes:

  - Run the `debuild -S` command in your source tree to build a local source package
  - Run `dput ppa:yourusername/ppa ../projectname_*_source.changes` to upload the local source package to [your remote PPA in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/people/+me/+archive)
- **Give feedback** Don't forget to reply in the *Feedback* tab as explained above

Comment: Having run `debuild -S`, I see that "DistUtilsExtra.auto" didn't recognise some of the files, including help, translation and the desktop.in file, will this mean that the Desktop file and help won't work if I upload the changes file to my ppa?

Comment: Are you sure this is not a warning and that the error does not lie somewhere else? Please ask a separate question so that we can help you.

Comment: Posted [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165499/debuild-does-not-recognise-some-files).