# How to merge a branch in bzr?

Tags: bazaar

I am a participant in the Ubuntu App Showdown contest and I got some feedback https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/1183/feedback/ and I want to `merge` the `bzr` branch of M. Hall to my main branch.

How I can do this correctly because I don't want to cause any problem...

edit: I found this [How do I apply the fixes suggested from the App Review Board to my app?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163096/how-do-i-apply-the-fixes-suggested-from-the-app-review-board-to-my-app)

but I have a problem

```
chris@chris-Aspire-5732Z ~/Projects/MangaR/mangar $ bzr merge lp:~mhall119/ubuntu-app-reviews/mangar
bzr: ERROR: Branches have no common ancestor, and no merge base revision was specified.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means the two branches are completely unrelated. It's like trying to merge the Gnome project into the KDE project.

I think you have two options:

1. Apply the changes of `mhall` as a patch on your code.

   ```
   bzr branch lp:~yourbranch mangar
   bzr branch lp:~mhall119/ubuntu-app-reviews/mangar mhall-mangar
   bzr diff -r300..-1 mhall-mangar | (cd mangar; patch -p0)
   ```

   Instead of revision 300 use the revision number right before `mhall`'s commit. If in fact he made only one commit, you can use `-c-1` instead of `-r`
2. Copy the version of `mhall` on top of your code.

   ```
   bzr branch lp:~yourbranch mangar
   bzr branch lp:~mhall119/ubuntu-app-reviews/mangar mhall-mangar
   cp -r mhall-mangar/* mangar/
   ```

   After this check the differences, most of them you probably want to revert, and keep only the changes that were done by `mhall`.

Answer (score 3):

use the `-r0..-1` option with `bzr merge`

Example:

```
 bzr merge lp:~mhall119/ubuntu-app-reviews/mangar -r0..-1
```

I found this answer [here](http://selfdocumentingcode.blogspot.com/2009/04/merging-unrelated-branches-in-bazaar.html?showComment=1238859600000#c5863654407618025791)

I like this solution better than the currently accepted answer, because now you should be able to still merge future changes from upstream, and it should "just work"

Also, it might be beneficial for you to branch from the existing project, then move everything to a subdirectory, then commit, then merge from that new branch with `-r0..-1`

Example:

```
 cd ..
 bzr branch lp:~mhall119/ubuntu-app-reviews/mangar mangar_branch
 cd mangar_branch
 mkdir mangar
 bzr add mangar
 bzr mv * mangar
 bzr commit
 cd ../${YOUR_TARGET_BRANCH}
 bzr merge ../mangar_branch -r0..-1
```